# how i can Get radio group value oracle apex

Tags: oracle-apex

I HAVE A CLASSIC  REPORT created by below query

```
 select ROWID,
   COUNTRY_ID,
   COUNTRY_NAME,
   REGION_ID,
   APEX_ITEM.RADIOGROUP(1,COUNTRY_ID,COUNTRY_ID) ID
   from COUNTRIES
   WHERE REGION_ID LIKE '%'||:P1_NEW_1 ||'%' OR :P1_NEW_1 IS NULL
```

how i can get the radio group checked  value and set it in item (only one value checked ) , when button click.

Comment: Are you trying to get the value in the client-side (JavaScript) without submitting the page? Or server-side (PL/SQL) when the page is submitted? If it's client-side, then YotamWIS Constantini's suggestion should help. Let us know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add a dynamic action on click for jQuery $('[name=f01]'), and then get the value of the triggering element

I also suggest that when using apex_item add the "p_item_id" parameter, you can set it to

```
"f01_"||COUNTRY_ID
```

or something of that sort, and then you can easily play with it using JS